# (imageio or celery) Error closing: 'Image' object has no attribute 'fp'

Tags: python-2.7, celery, python-imageio

I am using imageio to write png images to file.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.cm as cm
import imageio # for saving the image
import matplotlib as mpl

hm_colors = ['blue', 'white','red']
cmap = mpl.colors.LinearSegmentedColormap.from_list('bwr', hm_colors)
data = np.array([[1,2,3],[5,6,7]])
norm = mpl.colors.Normalize(vmin=-3, vmax=3)
colormap = cm.ScalarMappable(norm=norm, cmap=cmap)
im = colormap.to_rgba(data)
# scale the data to a width of w pixels
im = np.repeat(im, w, axis=1)
im = np.repeat(im, h, axis=0)
# save the picture
imageio.imwrite("my_img.png", im)
```

This process is performed automatically and I noticed some Error messages saying:

```
Error closing: 'Image' object has no attribute 'fp'.
```

Before this message I get warning:

```
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/imageio/core/util.py:78: UserWarning: Lossy conversion from float64 to uint8, range [0, 1] dtype_str, out_type.__name__))
```

However, the images seem to be generated and saved just fine. 
I can't find data to recreate this message.

Any idea why I get this error and why it doesn't noticeably affect the results? I don't use PIL. 
One possible reason could come from using this in Celery.

Thanks!
L.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same issue using `imageio.imwrite` in Python 3.5.  It's a fairly harmless except for the fact that that it's stopping garbage collection and leading to excessive memory usage when writing thousands of images.  The solution was to use the `PIL` module, which is a dependency of `imageio`.  The last line of your code should read:

```
from PIL import Image
image = Image.fromarray(im)
image.save('my_img.png')
```